# Can not execute Powershell Script in .Net MVC Application

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have a .Net MVC application which need to check and get some information from another server via powershell command with code shown below. But app can not get information

```
try
{
string un = @"domainA\domainUserName";
System.Security.SecureString pw = new System.Security.SecureString();
string password = "";

string exchangeServerName = "ServerAdress/powershell";
foreach (char ch in password)
{
    pw.AppendChar(ch);
}

using (PowerShell _powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
{

    var credential = new PSCredential(un, pw);
    _powerShell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("Credential", credential);
    _powerShell.AddScript($"$Session = New-PSSession –ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri {exchangeServerName} -Credential $Credential -Authentication Kerberos -AllowRedirection");
    _powerShell.AddScript("Import-PSSession $Session");
    _powerShell.Invoke();
    _powerShell.AddScript(@"get-mailbox -identity " + mail + " | Select-Object ProhibitSendReceiveQuota");
    var results = _powerShell.Invoke();

    string size = "";
    string used = "";
    string size2 = "";
    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
    {
        size = (obj.Properties["ProhibitSendReceiveQuota"].Value.ToString());
    }

    _powerShell.AddScript(@"Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity " + mail + " | Select-Object Totalitemsize,DatabaseProhibitSendQuota");
    var results2 = _powerShell.Invoke();

    _powerShell.AddScript("Remove-PSSession $Session");
    _powerShell.Invoke();

    // 
    
}
}
```

Target server and source server are in different domains.
In local running app wroks perfectly. What can be cause this issue and how can I resolve issue.

Thank you.

Comment: What are the symptoms? What does `_powerShell.HadErrors` say after you call `Invoke()`? Check `_powerShell.Streams.Error` for errors.

Comment: You need same account on local and remote machine (group account).  Can you run script from command line manually?  Try so we can eliminate credential issues.  Usually you need Admin account.  Inside VS you do not automatically get admin unless you start VS by right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.